# Need MPPI Tuning help: Omni robot not following pure omni motion

Tags: navigation

My setup is:

- MPPI code ported to ROS Noetic and have a custom Omni
  robot.
- Overall code is running at 50 hz but MPPI is significantly slower and running at average of 1 hz, so model_dt is set to 0.09.

I have a global plan from move_base's GlobalPlanenr (Dijkshtra's algorithm). I have followed the tuning guide from ReadMe.md of nav2. My parameters are:

```
local_planner:
  time_steps: 56
  model_dt: 0.09
  batch_size: 1000
  vx_std: 0.2
  vy_std: 0.2
  wz_std: 0.4
  vx_max: 1.0
  vx_min: -1.0
  vy_max: 1.0
  wz_max: 0.8
  iteration_count: 1
  prune_distance: 1.5
  transform_tolerance: 0.1
  temperature: 0.3
  gamma: 0.015
  motion_model: "Omni"
  visualize: false
  reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
  regenerate_noises: false
  TrajectoryVisualizer:
    trajectory_step: 5
    time_step: 3
  AckermannConstraints:
    min_turning_r: 0.0
  critics: ["GoalCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
  GoalCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 5.0
    threshold_to_consider: 1.4
  GoalAngleCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 3.0
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
  PreferForwardCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 5.0
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
  ObstaclesCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    repulsion_weight: 1.5
    critical_weight: 20.0
    consider_footprint: true
    collision_cost: 10000.0
    collision_margin_distance: 0.1
    near_goal_distance: 0.5
    inflation_radius: 0.55 # (only in Humble)
    cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
  PathAlignCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 10.0
    max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.07
    trajectory_point_step: 4
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
    offset_from_furthest: 33
    use_path_orientations: false
  PathFollowCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 5.0
    offset_from_furthest: 6
    threshold_to_consider: 1.4
```

When the start pose orientation and end pose orientation is same and globalpath is a straight line, the expected behaviour from robot is to produce pure omni motion but the robot tries to first align with the path and then align again with the goal when goal angle critic is triggered near the goal. Pure Omni motion is not happening in any scenario.

I have shared a video for better understanding: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ksEb2JXMQXH2hi7NP6XYdUNGweNYpxP-/view?usp=drivesdk)
Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you fix a custom codebase that isn't open-source.